# Partitioning by specific rows

Tags: sql, partitioning, hana

What we have is this, a table sorted by date and time:

```
date       | time        | amount | type
-----------+-------------+--------+-------
11/09/2014 | 11:13:03 AM | 1      | USE
11/09/2014 | 11:14:03 AM | 2      | USE
11/09/2014 | 12:13:03 AM | 10     | BUY
11/09/2014 | 12:15:03 AM | 1      | USE
11/09/2014 | 12:17:03 AM | 3      | USE
11/09/2014 | 12:18:03 AM | 1      | USE
11/09/2014 | 12:19:03 AM | 4      | USE
11/09/2014 | 13:13:03 AM | 15     | BUY
11/09/2014 | 14:13:03 AM | 1      | USE
```

We want to build up a growing sum of USE transactions between each BUY transaction. I.e. we want to come up with a table like this:

```
date       | time        | amount | type
-----------+-------------+--------+-------
11/09/2014 | 11:13:03 AM | 1      | USE
11/09/2014 | 11:14:03 AM | 3      | USE
11/09/2014 | 12:13:03 AM | 10     | BUY
11/09/2014 | 12:15:03 AM | 1      | USE
11/09/2014 | 12:17:03 AM | 4      | USE
11/09/2014 | 12:18:03 AM | 5      | USE
11/09/2014 | 12:19:03 AM | 9      | USE
11/09/2014 | 13:13:03 AM | 15     | BUY
11/09/2014 | 14:13:03 AM | 1      | USE
```

You see that the amount in each *USE* transaction is the sum of the old value and the value in the previous *USE* transaction. And it resets after every *BUY* transaction.

Partitioning via *BUY/USE* only creates two partitions, and thus the sum over them is not the one we want to have. We want to partition at every *BUY* transaction.

Afer having spent a day on trying to solve this, I want to ask how to do this in SQL and whether it is even possible? We are using SAP HANA, in case it matters.

Comment: This is possible in SQL.  However, SAP Hana supports neither CTEs nor window functions, making it much, much more difficult in that dialect.

Comment: You might be referring to an earlier version. Windows functions are [possible now](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/a353327519101495dfd0a87060a0d3/content.htm). Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify groups that end in "USE".  One method is to do a cumulative reverse sum of "USE" values.  Then do a cumulative sum, partitioned on this group.

I don't have access to SAP Hana, but this is standard SQL:

```
select t.*,
       sum(amount) over (partition by grp order by date, time) as cume_amount
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when type = 'BUY' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by date desc, time desc) as grp
      from table t
     )  t
```